# DataContract Versioning

Tags: c#, wcf, datacontractserializer, datacontract

I have been reading this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/data-contract-versioning?redirectedfrom=MSDN article about data contract versioning.

It says that changing the name of the data member is a breaking change.

It then also says that if a data contract with a new field is deserialized into the old data contract(without the new field), it would work since the new field will be ignored. Also, old contract being deserialized into new contract would also work with the new field assigned a default value (assuming that the new field does not have IsRequired attribute, in which case it will throw an exception).

Now, lets say I have a data contract with a field called "MyField"(without IsRequired attribute) and I change the field name to "MyField1", that would be equivalent to deleting "MyField" and adding "MyField1". That should mean that if new contract is deserialized into old contract, "MyField" will be initialized to default value and vice versa.

So by breaking change, Microsoft mean that the field will not be set with correct values and not that it will throw an exception. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Breaking Change does not necessarily mean the program will crash, it means the program will behave different than it used to.

Comment: [Wiktionary: breaking change](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/breaking_change): *A change in one part of a software system that potentially causes other components to fail...* In this case the failure would be data loss

Comment: The official document is not very clear. I have not paid attention to the version of the data contract before. Thank you for your question. I also learned a lot.

Comment: Glad to hear that @TheobaldDu